# How to stub a method with complex object as parameter in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

My Class looks in this way:

```
   public class MyClass{
        A obj;
        List<B> Obj1;
      }
    public class A{
     C obj2;
     }
    public class B{
      List values;
    }
```

There is a method `addToCart()` in class `MyClassImpl` as below:

```
          class MyClassImpl{
               addToCart(MyClass c, String x, String Y, String Z);

         }
```

I am writing a Test Class to `MyClassImpl`. I am able to pass test values of x,y and z to the `addToCart()`, but as c is a complex object, how do I stub this method with values? Setting values deeper is taking time for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test does not rely on a populated instance of `MyClass` being passed to `addToCart()` then you can mock it ...

```
MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
String x = "some x";
String y = "some y";
String y = "some z";

MyClassImpl sut = new MyClassImpl();
sut.addToCart(myClass, x, y, z);

// continue with test assertions ...
```

This will work as long as your usage of `addToCart()` does not care about the contents or behaviour of `myClass`.

If, however, your test usage of `addToCart()` has some expectations of the contents or behaviour of `myClass` then you must pass an actual instance of 'MyClass" which has been constructed to meet those expectations. Or if, as your OP suggests, "setting values deeper" is time consuming and, perhaps, your test only cares about some limited aspect of `MyClass` then you can use Mockito to mock those limited aspects. For example:

```
MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
Mockito.when(myClass.getX()).thenReturn("some test specific value"); 
Mockito.when(myClass.doX()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("some test specific exception");
String x = "some x";
String y = "some y";
String y = "some z";

MyClassImpl sut = new MyClassImpl();
sut.addToCart(myClass, x, y, z);

// continue with test assertions ...
```

**Edit 1**: based on your comment "there is a condition for null check for the Myclass object myclass and myclass.getX() inside addToCart()" ...

```
X x = Mockito.mock(X.class);
Mockito.when(myClass.getX()).thenReturn(x);
```

... will ensure that the null-check on `MyClass.getX()` within `addToCart()` passes safely. And, of course, any null check on the `myClass` instance passed to `addToCart()` will pass safely since you have created a mocked instance of `MyClass` and passed that into `addToCart()` and that instance, clearly, is not null.

Comment: it is like myClass.getX(), again getX() has some three variables which are classes, those classes are again deeper.

Comment: Understood, so mocking `MyClass` can help you there though if you need to mock `X` within `MyClass` and then `Y` within `X` you might soon find that creating a **real** instance of `MyClass` might be less time consuming and might result in more readable test code.

Comment: there is a condition for null check for the Myclass object myclass and myclass.getX() inside addToCart(), Is there any way I can Stubb to override the null check or such that the object and value not be null

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to mock the `myClass.getX()` call within `addToCart()`.